# Quick way to save multiple open graphics windows in R?

Tags: r, function, graphics, shortcut, graphic

I know that I can save an image in a graphics window via a few options:

- Right click image > Save...
- File > Save as > ....

I also know that I can save multiple images by opening/saving to an external file (e.g., `save()`, `pdf()`, `jpg()`, `png()`, `tiff()`, etc.)

However, **is there a way to save multiple OPEN device window images in R?**

This would perhaps be necessary in instances such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510522/how-to-start-new-graphics-window-and-or-graphics-page-in-r) or in instances in which plotting very complicated graphics takes so long that you'd rather not have to regenerate them (after initially failing to save the files to an external file).

P.S. I'm using R version 3.3.1 (64-bit) on Windows 7 machine. NOT using RStudio.

Comment: what do you mean with "simultaneously"? I understand that your problem is to save the current opened devices, am i right?

Comment: @Nicola, I guess I was considering wrapping up saving all open device windows into a single function. But that seems more specific than I really need. A multi-step approach should work fine too if concise and simple. I'll edit my question to get rid of "simultaneously."

Comment: Are you looking for a way to move between multiple graphical devices? (i.e. make a plot, start a new quartz window, switch the active device back to the first window and save it?) See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/dev.html

Comment: why you couldn't save your graphs one by one?

Comment: I mean: plot the first graph and save it with `save()` function, plot the second one and `save()` etc. It is not so clear what is your problem

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use a `for` loop? something like for( i in 1:50) {pdf(...); <Plot code>; dev.off()} Generally when I want to Automate plot generation that is how I do it.

Comment: You're all missing the important detail of the question. I want to save ALREADY OPENED graphics windows. As in, the solution cannot require regenerating the graphics.

Comment: Just list all the current graphics devices with `dev.list()`  Loop through the list and save each one.

Comment: @G5W I had no idea I could do that. Thank you for the helpful response. How do I reference the devices in an actual loop? (i.e., do I just use the number of the device)? If you draw this up as a quick answer showing an example of its use I'll accept it.

Comment: To all downvoters: this question has been clarified and therefore I ask that you vote on the quality of the question itself, not on any previous misunderstandings hashed out in the comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all the current graphics devices with `dev.list()`. Then loop through the list and save each one.

Open your multiple graphics windows. Then run:

```
for(d in dev.list()) {
    dev.set(d)
    Name = paste("Image", d, ".jpg", sep="")
    dev.copy(jpeg, Name)
    dev.off()
}
```

Of course,  you can use formats other than jpeg if you like.